# Python - change pixel value

Tags: python

I have used this code to change the pixel value of image,

```
im=Image.open("image.jpg")
pix=im.load()
pix[50,50]=(70,70,70)
```

it is work well with me, but when I use a png image everything is okay and the changes are saved to the image, but when I use a JPG image the changes are not saved to the image.
Is there something missing in the code, do I need to save the changes , and how would I do ??

Comment: It seems to me in neither case pixels get saved unless you also called some `save` method .. can you update the snippet?

Comment: Next time use button `{}` on pasted code.

Comment: Are you using PIL? pillow? (Your code snippet leaces a lot of guess-work.)

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: There is no error message, print pix[50,50] will print the new value, however the new value temporary

Comment: I use im.save("newImage.jpg"), but the new image has the same value of the first image

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
im.putpixel((50,50), (70, 70, 70))
```

or you can also do:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# pix has 4 channels for png and 3 for jpg
pix = np.array(im)

pix[50, 50, 0] = 70      # 0 accesses the first channel
pix[50, 50, 1] = 70      # 1 accesses the second channel
pix[50, 50, 2] = 70      # 2 accesses the third channel

Image.fromarray(pix).save('new_img.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is the same, the new image has the same value of the first image

Comment: Is the problem with using JPG ?

Comment: so if you try _italic_ 'pix[50, 50, 0] = 70'
and then if you _italic_ 'print pix[50, 50, 0] ' isn't the printed value 70? I have tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: If you are trying to change a single pixel only and save the jpg this pixel might be lost since jpg is a compression format which means some data is lost when saved as jpg. Try to change a big patch of the image  pix[50:100, _italic_ '50:100, 0] = 70  pix[50:100, 50:100, 1] = 70  pix[50:100, 50:100, 2] = 70 ' and then save it to a file. You should definitely see the change.

Comment: I think this is the problem "lossless compression", thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

**Save the image with the previous file name.** That worked for me well

```
im=Image.open("image.jpg")
pix=im.load()
pix[50,50]=(70,70,70)
img.save("image.jpg")
```